# C++ string: Invalid pointer error

Tags: c++

I am getting an invalid pointer error when I call the below function. Why is this happening?

```
void Get(const char* value)
{
    string st("testing string");
    string val = st.substr(1, st.length()); 
    value = val.c_str();        
}

int main()
{
    const char *val = NULL;
    GetVal(val);
    cout<<val;
}
```

The objective is to return the substring.

Answer (score 8):

`val` variable inside `Get()` gets destroyed once `Get()` returns, thus the pointer to `val` body becomes invalid. Also `value` parameter is a copy of the original pointer, so the original `val` pointer in `main()` function is left unchanged and still holds a null pointer value.

Change it to

```
string Get()
{
    string st("testing string");
    string val = st.substr(1, st.length()); 
    return val;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I see two mistakes:

- You assign a `val.c_str()` to a pointer that is local to `GetVal()`;
- `val` is destroyed at the end of `GetVal()`, so the pointer value would be invalid anyway.

Answer (score 1):

Prefer using `std::string`.

```
string Get()
{
    string st("testing string");
    return st.substr(0, st.length()/2);//returning substring
}

string s = Get();
```

By the way, an interesting article (by Herb Sutter) you would like to read now is:

[GotW #88: A Candidate For the “Most Important const”](http://herbsutter.com/2008/01/01/gotw-88-a-candidate-for-the-most-important-const/)